# Access query to SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, ms-access, case

I am trying to convert an Access query to a SQL Server view. I have 3 boolean columns in the Access query `MedTypeHealth`, `MedTypeSocial` and `MedTypeEducation`.

In Access I use this formula:

```
MedType: IIf([MedTypeHealth],"H"," ") & IIf([MedTypeSocial],"S"," ") & IIf([MedTypeEducation],"E"," ")
```

If all 3 flags are set, this returns `'HSE'` and if only the `Health` flag is set, I get me `'H'`.

I have the same columns in the SQL Server view.

How can I get the equivalent result in a SQL Server view? What T-SQL functions and code should I use?

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? There are loads of resources out there to help answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has no boolean datatype, so you would probably use a small integer value, or a bit.

Then, I would recommend `concat_ws()` and conditional expressions: it happily ignores `null` values, which simplifies the `case` expressions:

```
concat_ws('',
    case when MedTypeHealth    = 1 then 'H' end,
    case when MedTypeSocial    = 1 then 'S' end,
    case when MedTypeEducation = 1 then 'E' end
) as MedType
```

Comment: There is a difference between this and your original code. If the flag <> 1, then your original code appends a space character " " but this appends empty string. Just beware.  @NigelV

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `IIF` function.

- Replace double quotes with single quotes to indicate strings in SQL Server
- Replace `&` with `+` to concatenate strings in SQL Server
- You need to explicitly tell the comparison like `[MedTypeHealth]=1` in SQL Server
- SQL Server does not have boolean. You can use `bit` (which is 0 or 1) but you cannot do `SUM()` operation on it. If you need `SUM()` operation, either use another numeric type (`tinyint`, `smallint`, etc.) or do an explicit type cast `cast(MedTypeSocial as smallint)`

Here is an example you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTestTable1] (
      [MedTypeHealth] bit
    , [MedTypeSocial] bit
    , [MedTypeEducation] bit
)

INSERT INTO [MyTestTable1] 
VALUES 
      ( 1, 0, 1)
    , ( 0, 0, 1)
    , ( 1, 1, 1)
    , ( 1, 0, 0)
    , ( 0, 0, 0)

SELECT 
    *
    , IIf([MedTypeHealth]=1,'H',' ') + IIf([MedTypeSocial]=1,'S',' ') + IIf([MedTypeEducation]=1,'E',' ') WithSpace
    , IIf([MedTypeHealth]=1,'H','') + IIf([MedTypeSocial]=1,'S','') + IIf([MedTypeEducation]=1,'E','') WithoutSpace
FROM 
    [MyTestTable1]

---- drop when done. uncomment first
-- DROP TABLE [MyTestTable1]
```

Comment: Thanks very much, K4M. The SQL Runs, and SQL checker gives the expression a clean bill of health but the View Designer in SQL Management Studio complains about the Equals sign. If I put in iif(dbo.TblContacts.MedTypeHealth = 1, 'H', ' ') as Health, I get an error: Error in list of function arguments: '=' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text. How do I make the parser recognise =?

Comment: Maybe you were missing `SELECT`. Just updated my answer. Try the new complete example

Comment: Thanks K4M, I have tested your answer and it works, but unfortunately not in the the SQL Management View Designer. I have reported this to Microsoft as a bug, but as this problem was still there in SQL server 2014, I doubt whether they will get round to fixing it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use the view designer very much, only to filter some records when editing records. Didn't notice you were asking for a solution to work in the designer. Good luck